# Power Query - matching columns from different tables to reconcile data

Tags: powerquery, data-cleaning, string-matching

I am trying to reconcile some project data. I have one main table where I extracted the projects I need to reconcile. In Table 1, the project names have an extra label or identifier and Table 2 has the "matching" project without the labels. I am trying to match the projects so that I can update values in other columns and eventually replace the projects in the main table with the changes.

Question: Is there an efficient way to do this? I will need to do this on a monthly basis.

Example:
Table 1 - with labels/project identifiers (AB or DDPC)

| Project Name | Profit | Hours | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROJ123AB - GeneralStoreFront | 100 | 15 | 1000 |
| PROJ123 - DDPCGeneralStoreBack | 100 | 5 | 200 |
| PROJ999AB - MerchStoreFrontDDPC | 100 | 5 | 800 |
| PROJ999AB - MerchStoreBack | 100 | 10 | 500 |
| PROJ111 - AllStoresDDPC | 100 | 10 | 500 |
| PROJ999-01AB - MerchStore123 | 100 | 10 | 500 |
| PROJ111-01AB - AllStores123DDPC | 100 | 10 | 500 |

Table 2 - no labels/project identifiers

| Project Name | Profit | Hours | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROJ123 - GeneralStoreFront | 125 | 50 | 2000 |
| PROJ123 - GeneralStoreBack | 200 | 15 | 500 |
| PROJ999 - MerchStoreFront | 50 | 50 | 300 |
| PROJ999 - MerchStoreBack | 200 | 10 | 200 |
| PROJ111 - AllStores | 10 | 10 | 100 |
| PROJ999-01 - MerchStore123 | 100 | 10 | 500 |
| PROJ111-01 - AllStores123 | 100 | 10 | 500 |

I tried splitting the Project Name column in Table 1 to for only the project number (ex PROJ123) and the same for Table 2 then created a custom column in Table 2 with IF statements referencing back to Table 1 Project Name (with only PROJ#) but the values did not return properly.

Example:
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "NEW Sales", each if #"Table1"[PROJ] = [PROJ] then #"Table1"[Sales] else "no match"). But this returned "no match" for all rows.

Ideally the final table will look something like this:

| Project Name | Profit | Hours | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROJ123 - GeneralStoreFront | 112.5 | 65 | 1000 |
| PROJ123 - GeneralStoreBack | 150 | 20 | 200 |
| PROJ999 - MerchStoreFront | 75 | 55 | 800 |
| PROJ999 - MerchStoreBack | 150 | 20 | 500 |
| PROJ111 - AllStores | 55 | 20 | 500 |
| PROJ999-01 - MerchStore123 | 100 | 20 | 500 |
| PROJ111-01 - AllStores123 | 100 | 20 | 500 |

***EDITS: Added 2 more rows to each table to show another variation of Project Name and clarification on what I need to do with the other columns after I find the matching project "pairs".

Profit column to be averaged between the two project "pairs".
Hours column to be summed between the two project "pairs".
Sales column to use value from Table 1 [Sales].

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer

```
let Source = Table1 & Table.RemoveColumns(Table2,{"Sales"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"AB","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Project Name"}),
#"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","DDPC","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Project Name"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced Value2", {"Project Name"}, {
    {"Profit", each List.Average([Profit]), type number},
    {"Hours", each List.Sum([Hours]), type number},
    {"Sales", each List.Sum([Sales]), type nullable number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Method: remove the sales column from Table2. Append table 1. Replace text AB with null. Replace text DDPC with null. Group and take sum/average as needed. Basic powerquery operations you can do from the interface

Comment: Thanks @horseyride. I attempted your solution and discovered there's another variation of the Project Name (extra subcode) in Table 1. I edited my OP to reflect this. Is there a way I can look for substring 'AB' and trim that instead? Also, your result table has an additional 3 rows. Those 3 projects should be grouped with the other projects but it didn't because of the extra 'DDPC' label.

Comment: edited answer.  if this doesn't work perhaps someone else can help you. Changing the question and the  requirements after answer is posted is not good form.